# Java Casting Object to Type?

Tags: java

I want to select the items in the JList specific to what the patient already clicked. If I click on the 3rd patient, the JList will select the items that patient selected.

In the PatientConList are the condition objects for that patient.

**When you add a patient you do this:**

```
List PatientConditions1 = new ArrayList();
PatientConditions1 =  ConditionsJList.getSelectedValuesList();
```

**Then when you click on a patient it does this**

```
public void MakePatientJListSelected(ArrayList PatientConList) {
    //this makes selected, so get condition array off patient.
    //so call this from patient jlist listener
    ConditionsJList.clearSelection();
    //get number - 1, so then 0 = first
    ArrayList<Conditions> PassedIn = PatientConList;
    ArrayList SelectList = new ArrayList();

    for(Conditions p: PassedIn)
    {
       int Num = p.getNumber();
       Num = Num - 1;
       SelectList.add(Num);
    }    

    //int startSel = 0;
    //int endSel = 0;
    //ConditionsJList.setSelectionInterval(startSel, endSel);

    for(int k=0;k<PassedIn.size();k++)
    {
        int startSel2 = k;
        int endSel2 = k;
        ConditionsJList.addSelectionInterval(startSel2, endSel2);
    }    
}
```

Sorry, Basically I have a JList and you can select the conditions you want and click add. this adds the list of conditions to the patient.

Basically when you select a patient to view I want it so that the jlist conditions for that patient are selected on the jlist.

Im getting this error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to DentistAppNew.Conditions

My patient class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Patient {

private int AccountNumber;
private String Name;
private int Age;
private String Address;
private String  Sex;
private String Phone;
private List<Conditions> ConditionNames;

public Patient( int AccountNumber1,
                String Name1, 
                int Age1, 
                String Address1, 
                String Sex1, 
                String Phone1, 
                List<Conditions> ConditionNames1)
{                
    this.AccountNumber = AccountNumber1;
    this.Name = Name1;
    this.Age = Age1;
    this.Address = Address1;
    this.Sex = Sex1;
    this.Phone = Phone1;
    this.ConditionNames = ConditionNames1
}

public  int getAccountNumber() { return AccountNumber; }

public  String getName() { return Name; }

public int getAge() { return Age; }

public String getAddress() { return Address; }

public String getSex() { return Sex; }

public String getPhone() { return Phone; }

public List getConditionsList() { return ConditionNames; }

public  void setName(String Name1) { this.Name = Name1; }

public void setAge(int Age1) { this.Age = Age1; }

public void setAddress(String Address1) { this.Address = Address1; }

public void setSex(String Sex1) { this.Sex = Sex1; }

public void setPhone(String Phone1) { this.Phone = Phone1; }

}
```

my conditions class:

```
public class Conditions {

    private int Number;
    private String Name;

    public Conditions( int Number1,String Name1) {
        this.Number = Number1;
        this.Name = Name1;      
    }   

    public  int getNumber() {
        return Number;
    }

    public  String getName() {
        return Name;
    }   
}
```

Comment: What line are you getting that exception on?

Comment: And this is why you should use generics... if you weren't using raw types, you would have this error at *compile* time.

Comment: its at the first for loop!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the list your are getting passed is a list of strings, and not a list of Conditions as you assume here:

```
for(Conditions p: PassedIn)
```

However, you are giving us very little to go on. What is the full error message?

Also, try changing the type of the `MakePatientJListSelected` to `ArrayList<Condition>`. I think you will find that the compiler will tell you that it expects an `ArrayList<String>` there.

Comment: This is where the compiler stops yes. 
And that is the error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to DentistAppNew.Conditions

Alsi it will not let me change the type of the method, cannot find symbol

Answer (score 2):

Your method takes the input ArrayList you have to down cast it

```
ArrayList<Conditions> PassedIn = (ArrayList<Conditions>)PatientConList;
```

Comment: I have changed as you said, but it stops working at the first for loop

Comment: That's because your arraylist does not contains Conditions objects. That is, the objects are of some other type. Try to debug it and check it out. Also, if you are expecting to receive ArrayList<Conditions> change your method declaration accordingly.